# SQL why wont this let me select a blank value and a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I have the following UDF.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList]
        (@list      varchar(MAX),
         @delimiter char(1) = N',')
    RETURNS @tbl TABLE ([Value]     varchar(200)) 
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @chrind INT
       DECLARE @Piece nvarchar(4000)

       SELECT @chrind = 1
       WHILE @chrind > 0
          BEGIN
            SELECT @chrind = CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@list)
             IF @chrind > 0
                SELECT @Piece = LEFT(@list,@chrind - 1)
             ELSE
                SELECT @Piece = @list
             INSERT @tbl([Value]) VALUES(@Piece)
             SELECT @list = RIGHT(@list,LEN(@list) - @chrind)
             IF LEN(@list) = 0 BREAK
          END

       RETURN

    END
```

I call this function with the following code example from a where clause in my sprocs:

```
WHERE u.[Owner] IN 
 (SELECT [VALUE] 
  FROM dbo.udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList(@Owners, ','))
```

I use this where statement in sprocs that I use for reporting services multivalue parameters. When a user selects just blank for the value it returns the correct data but if a user selects a blank value and another value that actually has text it does not return the blank value owners anymore, just the owners from the text? Any ideas? I take it something is wrong with the function?

Comment: What a good name for a simple split function!

Comment: `but if a user selects a blank value and another value that actualyl has text it does not return the blank value owners anymore` I don't get it.

Comment: What gets passed as parameters to the function in both cases? (Use SQL Profiler to find out if you don't know) Maybe RS will automatically send the full list by default unless one other option is selected.

Comment: I have no idea how to use sql profiler but for example an owner could be 15103N which gives me only unit e1601 which is correct and if I select just the blank for owner it gives me e1502 which is correct but then when I select both blank and 15103N for owners it only gives me e1601.....

Comment: Mwahaha. Oops... Try to pass the following to the TVF: '15103n,,'

Comment: @Martin Nope, returns `'15103n'` and `''`, which is what he presumably needs. :)

Comment: @Denis `SELECT [VALUE] FROM dbo.udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList('15103n,,', ',')` returns a NULL for me (SQL 2005) @anicolais I suggest you just fire up SQL Profiler and learn how to use it. It's not difficult and it's very useful for debugging this sort of issue.

Comment: @Martin Your statement returns two values for me. And I listed them above. (`Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7600: ) `)

Comment: Sorry the function call is now updated to what it is supposed to be. I was testing it thats why it was a blank being passed into it. Now it is @Owners.

Comment: I used SQL Profiler and it passes no blank value into the @Owner parameter....

Comment: only when it is only blank will it pass ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what I could gather from your comments it seems that you need a new splitting function. Here's what I use:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@s varchar(512),@sep char(1))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM Pieces
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
  )
```

It has a nice enumeration feature to it and it doesn't eat blanks. :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, won't `stop` always be greater than zero?

Comment: Surely the issue is with what is being sent from Reporting Services anyway. The OP is using multivalue parameters it must default to sending a complete comma delimited list of all values or the `in` would never work.

Comment: How do I call this function? The same As I would with mine in a sproc?

Comment: @Martin Well, owners are either having a full-fledged value or a downgraded 'empty string', if you pass a CSV ('o1,') you will select all the items that are related to either o1 or '' (not NULL).

Comment: But, it is generally a bad idea to specify a missing owner by assigning an empty string value to it.

Comment: I know, I didn't design this I am just writing the queries. SO how do I use this function I say 
WHERE u.[Owner] IN (SELECT [VALUE] FROM dbo.udf_SplitString(@Owners, ','))  it says invalid column name value.....

Comment: This still does not work. It still doesn't pass the blank value into the function

Comment: @anicolais I don't know what you are talking about. I mean, there are two kinds of blank, one being an empty string `''` and another is `NULL`. What are you passing to the TVF? If you need `''` on the right side, then embrace the parameter in isnull(@owners,''), if on the other then do isnull(u.owner,''). Hope that helps.

Comment: I need it to return '' for when I select blank in reporting services. It passes '' to the function when i only select blank but when I select blank and a value it only passes the value....waht do you mean by that last part of your comment? "then embrace the parameter in isnull(@owners,''), " Thanks

Comment: @anicolais Then you need to fix the client application. Because it does not behave in a consistent manner. It just has to pass `',15103N'` or `'15103N,'` and not just `'15103N'` because that means gimme all those items that belong to this owner. If you think that by specifying a particular owner should also return all those items without an owner you need to add another predicate which would always returns items that belong to no one. `or isnull(u.owner,'')=''`

Comment: It is supposed to only show the items belonging to that owner. The problem is if there is not owner and the user selects the blank value option along with another option that is not blank then it only returns the non blank owner because it ignores the blank value.

Comment: @anicolais What is the value of @owners in this case? When a user selects two options.

Comment: If you select blank and 1513ON in the Owners list filter in SSRS it passes @Owners=N'1513ON'

Comment: @anicolais It just goes to show that you need to fix your client application and not this stored procedure.

Comment: Well it ended up actually being an SSRS issue but thanks for all the help. I didn't design the app and this part of it is really bothering me along with others of course but I have no say over it so I just figure out ways around it ;)